# Detailed Reports tab in form report is showing blank in WFFM

Tags: wffm, reporting

I have configured Sitecore 8.2 update 4 into **CMS only mode** and configured WFFM with SQL databases.

When I submit a form and open form report it is showing the data into Summary tab but "Detailed Reports" tab is showing "No data has been set".

Is any body have any idea about this.

I have followed wffm with sql configuration steps from this blog post but no luck -

https://citizensitecore.com/2016/05/11/wffm-and-cms-only-mode-in-sitecore-8-1/

[image: Summary Tab]
[image: Detailed Reports]

Comment: You try check connect MongoDB. Because you submit form, Sitecore store data customer to MongoDB and it will MongoDB to Sql Server. Please check anaylytic config file.

Comment: @LêDuyMinh Actually it stored the data into sql database but not showing in detailed reports tab.When i export the data using export form data to excel it give me all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used the same configuration on a recent project (WFFM with SQL data source, XDB disabled).

I raised the issue about the Detailed Reports Tab not working with Sitecore Support. I'm sorry to say that the response was that this tab will not work with with the SQL provider. As far as I know, it's a known limitation.

The tab uses tracking data (dropouts, failures). So with XDB turned off I guess it makes sense that it can't reference this data to generate the report.

Apologies this was about 12 months ago and I no longer have access to the original support ticket to give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a bug and sitecore support have registered the appropriate bug in the current version of the WFFM module. Please use the reference number 87110 for this bug.

They suggested us to hide this tab in CMS only mode.To hide the "Detailed Reports" tab, you can perform the following steps:

- go to the "/sitecore/client/Applications/WFFM/Pages/FormReport/PageSettings/TabControl/Detailed Reports" item in the "core" database,
- check the "IsHidden" field and save the item.